# Fatal : no bootable Medium Found! System halted

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

Could anyone help me to find a way to resolve the error which i am getting in my Virtual Machine box in windows 7
Fatal: No bootable medium found! System halted!

Comment: My question might have your answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883014/how-to-successfully-make-a-virtual-machine-work-using-only-a-computer

Answer (score 0):

Attach a virtual disk that contains a bootable volume.